# Разъясните поведение iif

Tags: angular, rxjs

Я предполагал что iif (закоментированный) делает то же самое, что и переписанный if. Iif возвращается на switchMap. проблема в том, что когда доходит до `iif`, то выполнались оба блока (true блок и false блок). Почему так?

```
private sendRequest<T>(
    method: EQueryMethod,
    url: string,
    body: any,
    headers: RequestHeaders,
    type: 'json' | 'multipart'
  ): Observable<T> {
    const platform = Capacitor.getPlatform();
    return of({}).pipe(
      switchMap(
        (s) => {
          if (platform === 'android') {
            return this.sendRequestAndroid(method, url, body, headers, type);
          } else {
            return this.sendRequestWeb(
              method,
              url,
              method === EQueryMethod.GET ? {} : body,
              method === EQueryMethod.POST ? {} : body,
              headers
            );
          }
        }
        // iif(
        //   () => platform === 'android',
        //   this.sendRequestAndroid(method, url, body, headers, type),
        //   this.sendRequestWeb(
        //     method,
        //     url,
        //     method === EQueryMethod.GET ? {} : body,
        //     method === EQueryMethod.POST ? {} : body,
        //     headers
        //   )
        // )
      ),
      take(1)
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть в том, что if != iif.

iif выполняет оба observable, но возвращает в результат только один, в зависимости от условия. Тогда как обычный if выполняет только тот, который соответствует условию.Такое поведение всплывает обычно на сложных конструкциях, тогда как на простых, поведение кажется идентичным if.

Из документации: Checks a boolean at subscription time, and chooses between one of two observable sources.
В переводе: Проверяет логическое значение во время подписки и выбирает один из двух наблюдаемых источников.

Соответственно, есть подписка именно на два источника, и выбирается один.

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://tyapk.ru/blog/post/rxjs-iif-feature)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Не знал об этом ньюансе

Comment: Сам полгода назад наткнулся на эту штуку на проде, было неприятно)